# How do I fix this CRC32 Error while using DotNetZip?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetzip

I am using the DotNetZip Library to generate a Zip File from byte arrays being retrieved from a SQL Server Database. I keep getting CRC32 as 0000000x0 for some of the files due to which the entire archive gets corrupted.

I have tried implementing the solution on [DotNetZip How to fix 0000000 CRC32 issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730893/dotnetzip-how-to-fix-0000000-crc32-issue), but it still does not resolve the issue.

Here's my Controller method:

```
 using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                //outputStream.Position = 0;
                using (var z = new ZipFile())
                {
                    while (j < a.Length)
                    {
                        //SQL Connection Code to retrieve base64 string called attachment
                        if (b.attachment != null)
                        {
                            string attachment = b.attachment;
                            byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment);
                            string contentType = b.filetype;

                            if (contentType.Equals("application/pdf"))
                            {
                                var newname = "D:\\Pdf_" + randomGenerator() + ".pdf";
                                z.AddEntry(newname, byteArray);
                            }
                            else if (contentType.Equals("text/plain"))
                            {
                                var newname = "D:\\Txt_" + randomGenerator() + ".txt";
                                z.AddEntry(newname, byteArray);
                            }
                            else if (contentType.Equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") || contentType.Equals("application/msword"))
                            {
                                var newname = "D:\\Doc_" + randomGenerator() + ".docx";
                                z.AddEntry(newname, byteArray);
                            }
                            else if (contentType.Equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheet.document") || contentType.Equals("application/msexcel") || contentType.Equals("application/vnd.ms-excel") || contentType.Equals("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
                            {
                                var newname = "D:\\Doc_" + randomGenerator() + ".xlsx";
                                z.AddEntry(newname, byteArray);
                            }
                            else if (contentType.Equals("image/jpeg") || contentType.Equals("image/png") || contentType.Equals("image/jpg"))
                            {
                                var newname = "D:\\Img_" + randomGenerator() + ".jpeg";
                                z.AddEntry(newname, byteArray);
                            }
                            else if (contentType.Equals("image/svg") || contentType.Equals("image/svg+xml"))
                            {
                                var newname = "D:\\SVG_" + randomGenerator() + ".svg";
                                z.AddEntry(newname, byteArray);
                            }
                            outputStream.Flush();
                            z.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;
                            z.Save(outputStream);

                            outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            outputStream.Position = 0;

                            j++;
                        }


                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.Error = "Attachment Data Not Found!";
                            return View();
                        }
                    }
                    //outputStream.Seek(0, 0);

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.BufferOutput = false;
                    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "ZipDownload_" + randomGenerator() + ".zip");
                    z.Save(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.End();
                    return File(outputStream, "application/zip", "ZipDownload_" + randomGenerator() + ".zip");
}
}
return View();
}
```

I have also tried setting the ParallelDeflateThreshold to -1, but that does not change anything.

Apart from this, I have tried using System.IO.Compression to generate a ZipArchive, but the problem of CRC32 still remains.

I am able to download the files individually and none of them are corrupted.

Comment: Why are you calling `ZipFile.Save` multiple times? I think you're meant to do one or more `ZipFile.AddEntry` and then a single `Save`. Also you're mixing your `MemoryStream` and `Response.OutputStream`. I believe just saving to the `MemoryStream` once, and then passing that to the `File` method should work.

Comment: @Wazner you are correct. It was a dumb mistake for me to commit. Thanks for helping me solve this :D